# Validate and filter data in multiindex Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filtering, multi-index

I have a multi-index Pandas data-frame that looks like this:

```
            A     B     C
Num_X T1    0     1     5
      T2    4     0     2

Num_Y T1    0     2     6
      T2    4     0     4
```

Wherever an element is 0 it should be zero for all other first index, the specific second index and the column e.g (Num_X, T1, A) is 0 and so all elements (*, T1, A) should be zero. My first question is how to make sure that's the case.

The second question is how I can get rid of these 0 values and make them nan. For the above data after verification and filtering, I expect the following Pandas data frame:

```
            A     B     C
Num_X T1    nan   1     5
      T2    4     nan   2

Num_Y T1    nan   2     6
      T2    4     nan   4
```

I'm not sure if I'm the stupid one or Pandas is complicated. Haven't been able to figure it out after spending quite a few hours on it.
Definitely appreciate your help.

Comment: `df[df == 0] = np.nan`

Comment: Thanks. How do I sanity check to make sure the equivalent elements are also 0 (my first question).